# Why HTTPWebRespnse takes longer even if HTTPWebRequest is sent long time back?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Hola check this code.

```
     var watch = new Stopwatch();
     watch.Start();
     var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://localhost:59449/stwebapi/chat?userId=john")) as HttpWebRequest;
     Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);

     Thread.Sleep(5000);

     watch.Restart();
     var response = request.GetResponse();
     Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);
```

I sent web request, waited for a long time and then got the response. Still response took longer to execute. The result I got was

```
00:00:00.1142339
00:00:03.1365544
```

Why response took me 3 seconds? 
Same response lag is there with asynchronous response.

I want GetResponse function to be executed immediately. How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Is that really related to two c# versions? If not, please remove those tags!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect that until you call `GetResponse`, the request isn't even sent... so your `Thread.Sleep` is basically doing you no good at all.

Why don't you just call `GetResponse` immediately? If it takes 3 seconds, then presumably that's how long the web server took to answer your request...

(As an aside, you should be using a `using` statement to make sure you dispose of the `WebResponse`; otherwise you'll end up with requests timing out as the connection pool waits for a connection to become available.)

Comment: Thanks Jon. I send 10 requests to this server and it takes almost 25 seconds to execute this thread. But as request does not start till I say getResponse there is nothing I could do much. THanks a lot...

Comment: @Omkarpanhalkar: If you're sending them all at roughly the same time, you may well be throttled by the connection pool - it's probably only *actually* sending 4 at a time. You may want to consider increasing the pool size.